# Count all embeddings of a geometric graph on the unit square that preserve all angles between existing edges

Tags: numerical-integration, graphs-and-networks

If I have a geometric graph with $n$ vertices in the unit square, is it possible to count all embeddings of the graph on the unit square that preserve angles between the existing edges?

It would essentially be a sort of `NIntegrate` problem involving a delta function whose argument is zero when all angles match some pre-specified set of angles, and I would have a $2n$-dimensional integral over the 2d domain. Is there an elegant way to set this up in Mathematica? Or even a way of counting these angle-preserving rigid motions without integrating?

Comment: Sounds like a hard math problem ... not so much a Mathematica one.

Comment: Perhaps I can try it with 5 points on a flat torus, and see if using delta functions set to pick out the correct angles I can evaluate the proportion of all point configurations that have those correct angles.